# BigQuery load data in append mode fails with hive partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have following data structure in my GCS

```
gs://BUCKET/inventory/date=2019-01-01/val=4/data.json
gs://BUCKET/inventory/date=2019-01-01/val=5/data.json

gs://BUCKET/inventory/date=2019-01-02/val=4/data.json
..
```

I want to load this data to existing Bigquery table with above hive partitioned fields. Existing BQ table also contains date and val columns which are referenced as hive partitions in the path

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
hive_partitioning = bigquery.external_config.HivePartitioningOptions()
hive_partitioning.mode = "AUTO"
hive_partitioning.source_uri_prefix = "gs://BUCKET/inventory" #path to hive partition data

job_config.hive_partitioning=hive_partitioning
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

uri = "gs://BUCKET/inventory/*.json"    #path to data

output_dataset_ref = client.dataset("dataset_name")
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, output_dataset_ref.table("table_name"), job_config=job_config
)  # API request

load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
print("Load complete for table {}".format("table_name"))
```

The job config is able to detect hive partitioned columns like date and value. But Job fails with error saying date column already exists.

However if I try to load data in new table, this code works and also able to add Hive partitioned columns. It only fails in case of appending to existing table.

detailed error message

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Failed to add partition key date (type: TYPE_DATE) to schema, because another column with the same name was already present.  This is not allowed. Full partition schema: [date:TYPE_DATE, val:TYPE_INT64].

I believe there is some issue with SDK, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Once you get to create a table, are you able to append data to the new created data, or do you get the same error?

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa Appending to existing table is failing with this error, if table doesn't exist it works fine

Comment: What I meant is if, once you create a new table, are you then able to append data to the table that you created (with this code)

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa No

Comment: I have been able to append new data with your code by [1: creating_table -> run your code changing 'job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND' for 'job_config.create_disposition = bigquery.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED' 
2: updating table-> run your code as it is] I first created the table(1), then added some more data to the bucket, and then updated the table(2). The observed behaviour is that the updated table has the previous data, the previous data again (repeated) and the new data I added.

Comment: Additional comment, I got your error when trying to create the table because in my data there was a column with the same name as the value stated in the path, but if it was your case you wouldn't have been able to create a new table, so I assume it is not the case